# Dynamic addition and removal of components Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

I have a container that contains two independent components.

The list of users comes to the first component from the backend part.

When clicking on a specific user, I need to show all of his complete information in the general container of the second independent component.

I presented my code in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-a3ojvq?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html,tsconfig.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent1%2Fcomponent1.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent1%2Fcomponent1.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent1%2Fcomponent1.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fbox%2Fbox.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbox%2Fbox.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fbox%2Fbox.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

It doesn't work quite right when removing an added component. It is not the selected component that is deleted, but only the last one.

Can anyone help me where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userId` is always `undefined` when calling `this.appService.removeUser(userId);`.
This is because of an issue in your template, you were calling `removeUser(options.userId)` instead of `removeUser(options.id)` :

```
  <div class="one-user" id="{{ options.id }}">
    <div>User ID: {{ options.id }}</div>
    <div>Name: {{ options.name }}</div>
    <div>Age {{ options.age }}</div>
    <button (click)="removeUser(options.id)">remove</button> 
  </div>
```

Also, notice that `viewContrainerRef.remove` takes the `index` of an element, not an id. So you need to be carefull to pass the right index. (0 for the fist element, 1 for the 2nd etc).

Comment: I changed the index, but it's still the same

Comment: Did you changed the argument of the clicked function ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated Stackblitz, but remove still not working as expected

Comment: I changed index, It works, thx